# Django transaction.commit_on_success - commit still happening despite error/exception, so how to debug?

Tags: django, django-models, transactions, django-orm

Using Django 1.3 with PostgreSQL 9.0, I have a multi-step object creation function/view, where:

1. The main object is created (have tried both MyModel.objects.create() and manually using object.save() methods) and,
2. Then m2m relationships are setup (they must follow the main object creation so that said object has an id to relate to).

Some of those relationships may fail, or some other problem may arise, thus I need the entire function to behave atomically.

I've tried wrapping the function with the transaction.commit_on_success decorator, as well as tried using commit_manually (and setting the commit point at the end of the function); but neither works.  That is, the main object is created and saved in the database, even when an exception is raised later on in the function.  This leaves the database in an inconsistent state, to put it politely.  So, how to debug this?  I've seen similar questions, but they had to do with using MySQL, whereas this kind of broken transaction is not supposed to happen with Postgres.  There were tickets on the Django Trac about this issue from years back, but they were supposedly fixed/resolved.  Could any Djangonauts out there provide enlightenment please?

Comment: @Daniel: not readily, unfortunately. If you know of things that would interfere with transactions, please advise, thanks.

Comment: I've found commit_on_success with sqlite to introduce odd behaviour on occasion, and found commit_manually to not work as expected. Do show some effected code, and show some errors or test cases that demonstrate this - without that you won't get answers here, or get the django devs to take this seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6669

I think for now you'll just need to call `transaction.rollback()` explicitly when you get an `IntegrityError`

Comment: Thanks - this looks to be related to what I'm seeing, at the least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to you, but the problem that brought me here was a failure to read the manual with regard to Django testing.

If you are testing code with transactions in it you need to use TransactionTestCase instead of TestCase, failure to do so will result in the tests seeing the behavior you describe.

Comment: Yes, and although `TestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase`, it *messes up* his parent's transaction handling. One can argue that it's a reasonable feature (as [the doc does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)), **but** it goes against the Liskov substitution principle. I found it quite counter-intuitive when I first encountered it.